# Puppet agent upgrade to 6.26 breaks function versioncmp()

Tags: upgrade, puppet

recently I upgraded puppet agent from 6.25 to 6.26 on the puppetserver and it seems that after upgrade all agents conected to the puppetserver fail to apply changes due to an internal server error caused by versioncmp() built in function.

The quick fix to keep going is to downgrade puppet agent on the server to 6.25

Error:

```
Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
```

Anyone managed to find where it breaks, and how versioncmp is changed in such manner that it sees 3 arguments?

Note: The function worked perfectly before and I did not changed anything in code.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PA-4189 for details. You need to make sure that the `puppetserver` package is updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that one of your manifests attempts to pass three arguments to the built-in `versioncmp()` function, which takes only two arguments (and never has taken more). Chances are excellent that the message is correct, and that change from Puppet 6.25 to 6.26 is that the latter now fails catalog compilation when the wrong number of arguments are passed, whereas the former did not.  Possibly you would see warnings in the catalog compiler's logs from earlier.

Very likely, then, the correct solution is to find the bad function call and fix it.  Certainly finding the function call that Puppet is complaining about is key to moving forward in any case.

Comment: I did check all the classes using the function, in fact the versioncmp() is used in all like this :
if versioncmp(var1,var2) something

So 2 arguments as far as I am concerned

Comment: @AndreiSolomon, my crystal ball tells me that it might be worthwhile to check for cases where one of the arguments is an unquoted literal, and in those cases to scrutinize the literal to make sure that there has been no substitution of commas (`,`) for periods (`.`).  You might also check Hiera data and explicit class parameters for the same kind of substitution, though that seems less likely to be a problem.  And perhaps verify that all of the arguments are scalars (specifically, strings), not arrays or hashes.

Comment: In any case, @AndreiSolomon, I suggest isolating the issue in the form of a [mre].  If that does not help you determine the nature of the problem for yourself then that information would allow for a more firm and specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will take another look and will get more into it